# Canvas as a root node in Scene Graph?

Tags: java, javafx

I'm new to JavaFX, I'm learning it. I tried to make a canvas object as a root to scene graph in the application. However, I'm not able to do it. I need to create a group or a pane object and add canvas to the one of them. I'm curious about why we are not able to assign a canvas object as a root node. Probably, I'm missing some major points.

The code I tried to compile is as follows;

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;

public class driver extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    Canvas canvas;

    @Override
    public void start( Stage stage ) {
        canvas = new Canvas(300, 300);
        Scene scene = new Scene(canvas, 300, 300);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't use Canvas as the parameter to the constructor(s) for Scene, because Scene takes a Parent as parameter. Canvas has superclass Node, not Parent. To verify, just check the Javadocs [for](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/Scene.html#constructor.summary) [both](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/canvas/Canvas.html) of them.